# Spring MVC maps parameter to .jsp instead of @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, url, maven, spring-mvc

I've created a sample spring-mvc app using maven archetype

```
mvn archetype:generate -D groupId=test.tool -D artifactId=test-D version=0.1-SNAPSHOT -D archetypeArtifactId=spring-mvc-jpa-archetype -D archetypeGroupId=org.fluttercode.knappsack
```

I've been trying to read some parameters from an URL:

```
package test.tool.controller;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/testReadRest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public class TestReadRestController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TestReadRestController.class);


// No Params
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getMainModel(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("varFromClient","[NOT SET]");
    model.addAttribute("tokenFromClient","[NOT SET]");
    return;
}

// http://localhost:8080/test/testReadRest/varPost
// read "varPost"
@RequestMapping(value = "/{varPost}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getVarFromURI(@PathVariable("varPost") String theVar, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("varFromClient",theVar);
    model.addAttribute("tokenFromClient","[NOT SET]");
    return;
   }
}
```

but the parameter isn't read when trying
    `http://localhost:8080/test/testReadRest/varPost`

instead, I get an error:

```
Problem accessing /soctoolset/WEB-INF/views/testReadRest/varPost.jsp. Reason: NOT_FOUND
```

Any suggestions?

[EDIT]

Here are the beans

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

and controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
        configure as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="test.tool" />

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Does the request actually end up in your handler method? I would think that the type level configuration prevents handling requests besides "/testReadRest". Try setting it to `@RequestMapping(value = "/testReadRest/**")` if this is an actual problem. Just ignore me if your mapping works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set up a new project with the archetype you used.

You are returning `void` from the `@Controller` method, so this [section from the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) applies:

> **`void`** if the method handles the response itself (by writing the response content directly, declaring an argument of type ServletResponse / HttpServletResponse for that purpose) or if the view name is supposed to be implicitly determined through a [RequestToViewNameTranslator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/RequestToViewNameTranslator.html) (not declaring a response argument in the handler method signature).

Thus, [the view is resolved based on the path](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator.html), in your case "varPost" or whatever you put at the end of the path. The extension ".jsp" is appended due to this default configuration:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

You could add the missing file, but I guess that's not what you want to do. Instead, you can change the handler method's signature and set a view explicitly, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{varPost}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getVarFromURI(@PathVariable("varPost") String theVar,
        Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("varFromClient", theVar);
    model.addAttribute("tokenFromClient", "[NOT SET]");
    return "someview";
}
```

This results in the following reasonable error:

> The requested resource (/testapp/WEB-INF/views/someview.jsp) is not available.

Now, you just need to create that view. You can then use the path variable without it interfering with the view resolution.

If you don't want to render a JSP, you could start by reading the documentation regarding the ["Supported method return types"](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types). If you want to handle the response completely yourself, you can return `void` again and [add the request and response as arguments](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods).

Comment: Thank you so much 4 bothering with my problem. Your references are most useful to a spring newbe like me. TY very much indeed!

Comment: And just tested it. Works like heaven. Feeling so happy :-D